# Authorize.net payment gateway Charge a Credit Card API for iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, payment-gateway, authorize.net

hello everyone as i am using payment gateway charge credit api but i am getting error while passing json object to api.and here my original JSON object which pass to charge credit api.

```
{
    "createTransactionRequest": {
        "merchantAuthentication": {
            "name": "XXXXXX",
            "transactionKey": "XXXXXXXX"
        },
        "refId": "123456",
        "transactionRequest": {
            "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
            "amount": "5",
            "payment": {
                "creditCard": {
                    "cardNumber": "5424000000000015",
                    "expirationDate": "2020-12",
                    "cardCode": "999"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is original  json request 
but in iOS while making JSON we get below JSON object and sequence of JSON object are change that's why we getting error from api.

```
{
    "createTransactionRequest": {
        "merchantAuthentication": {
            "name": "XXXXXX",
            "transactionKey": "XXXXXXX"
        },
        "refId": "123456",
        "transactionRequest": {
            "amount": "5",
            "payment": {
                "creditCard": {
                    "cardCode": "999",
                    "cardNumber": "5424000000000015",
                    "expirationDate": "2020-12"
                }
            },
            "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction"
        }
    }
}
```

after passing this JSON object to API, we will get bellow error

```
{
    "messages": {
        "resultCode": "Error",
        "message": [
            {
                "code": "E00003",
                "text": "The element 'transactionRequest' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child element 'amount' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'transactionType' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

here is my code for creating JSON object in app

```
var dict = Dictionary<String, Any>()
 dict=[
  "merchantAuthentication": [
    "name": "xxxxxxx",
    "transactionKey": "xxxxxxx"
  ],
  "refId": "5656",
  "transactionRequest": [
    "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
    "amount": "55",
    "payment": [
      "creditCard": [
        "cardNumber": "4111111111111111",
        "expirationDate": "2020-12",
        "cardCode": "999"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

after print this JSON sequence are changed

Comment: Please check the `payment` element is array object

Comment: Yes it is array of object..It's sequence issue .. how i can maintain sequence of JSON in app??

Comment: Please first try your json request with coma in postman first. if it's work then I'll send you code for create json request. And also send me your code so I get idea.

Comment: Yes i send JSON object which is get in app to postman but it also gives same error which we get in app..
here is my code,var dict = Dictionary<String, Any>()
dict=["merchantAuthentication":["name":"xxxxxx","transactionKey":"xxxxx"],"refId":"5656","transactionRequest":["transactionType":"authCaptureTransaction","amount":"55","payment":["creditCard":["cardNumber":"4111111111111111","expirationDate":"2020-12","cardCode":"999"]]]]
after print this object sequence are changed..

Comment: please add this code in your question instead of in comment

Comment: okay i have edit my question and add code

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia can you send me code to maintain sequence of JSON object in app.

Comment: Sure just a minute

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [the documentation](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/)? It's very clear from the linked page that what you're running into is a side effect of their translation of JSON elements to XML elements in the backend, specifically around the ordering of parameters in your JSON request:

> ## A Note Regarding JSON Support
>
> The Authorize.Net API, which is not
> based on REST, offers JSON support through a translation of JSON
> elements to XML elements. While JSON does not typically require a set
> order to the elements in an object, XML requires strict ordering.
> Developers using the Authorize.Net API should force the ordering of
> elements to match this API Reference.

Their examples below this block also show that their `transactionType` parameters appear as the *first* attribute in the `transactionRequest` object. **Tl;dr** - move your `transactionType` parameter up in your `transactionRequest` object:

```
{
    "createTransactionRequest": {
        "merchantAuthentication": {
            "name": "XXXXXX",
            "transactionKey": "XXXXXXX"
        },
        "refId": "123456",
        "transactionRequest": {
            "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
            "amount": "5",
            "payment": {
                "creditCard": {
                    "cardCode": "999",
                    "cardNumber": "5424000000000015",
                    "expirationDate": "2020-12"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try as per your instruction but it showing an error

{
    "messages": {
        "resultCode": "Error",
        "message": [
            {
                "code": "E00003",
                "text": "The element 'createTransactionRequest' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child element 'transactionType' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'transactionRequest' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'."
            }
        ]
    }
}

Answer (score -1):

please try with following code.

```
let merchantSub =   ["name": "XXXXXX",
                         "transactionKey": "XXXXXXX"]

    let childCreditCard = ["cardCode": "999",
                           "cardNumber": "5424000000000015",
                           "expirationDate": "2020-12"]

    let creditCard = ["creditCard":childCreditCard]

    let transactionRequest = ["amount": "",
                              "payment":creditCard,
                              "transactionType":""] as [String : Any]

    let merchantAuthentication = ["merchantAuthentication" :merchantSub,
                                  "refId" : "123456",
                                  "transactionRequest":transactionRequest] as [String : Any]

    let param = ["createTransactionRequest" : merchantAuthentication]


    if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: .prettyPrinted),
        let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(str)
    }
```

However I recommend to use class but for initial level do like this.

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)